# How to read HTML page source from facebook using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm trying to read a page source from facebook.
but I'm not getting the full page source.
if I run the same URL in postman or some other tool using HTTP GET, I get complete source.
below is my code, can anyone point out what I'm missing...
thanks

```
     string pagePath = "https://www.facebook.com/search/events/?q=Laurea+Ammattikorkeakoulu";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(pagePath);
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0";
        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        string responseString = "";

        HttpWebResponse getResponse2 = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: _“I'm trying to read a page source from facebook”_ – you’re not supposed to do that – scraping without explicit prior permission by Facebook is forbidden by the ToS. If you want to interact with Facebook and any content on it – use their API.

Comment: @CBroe the reason is, API doesn't provide a way to get events by location. But we can do that from browser, just trying to see if I can do that by scraping the page. I'm not going to use it on a commercial level.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what “level” you want to use it on – that doesn’t change the fact that the ToS simply don’t permit this.

Comment: @CBroe I see. is that the reason I'm unable to get the the page HTML? I mean, have they put in something to disable reading like this?

Comment: They have a lot of measures in place to prevent this, of course. Plus, most of the actual content is loaded in the background via JS anyway.